# Driver does not compile after kernel upgrade

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel

what kernel versions are included in 14.04LTS?
I have a vendor's vme driver that compiled in 3.16 but won't compile after the latest upgrade to 14.04.03 which has a 3.19 kernel (32-bit).  The struct "file" is not recognized any more, or at least members like file->f_dentry->d_iname.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The supported kernel versions in Ubuntu 14.04 (and its point releases) are 3.13, 3.16, 3.19 and 4.2, they are available in the packages `linux-image-generic`, `linux-image-generic-lts-utopic`, `linux-image-generic-lts-vivid`, and `linux-image-generic-lts-wily` respectively.